# CoreData object not populating with values

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have this peice of code that reads my coreData and paces it into an array of coredata objects.. i then get one of these coredata objects into its own var type however not all of the attributes are populated to begin with.

this is what my code looks like.

```
NSMutableArray *tempFinishing = [coreDataController readFinishing];
    for (int i = 0; i < [tempFinishing count]; i++) {
        currentProject = [[Project alloc] init];
        currentProject = [tempFinishing objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([currentProject.hasChange isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
```

when i check hasChange it comes back as nil... but heres the weird thing
if I do this in the console.

```
po currentProject.hasChange
```

returns nil

```
po currentProject.myID
```

returns myID "1234"

then

```
po currentProject.hasChange
```

returns "F" // which is incorrect it should be set at T and have seen debugged it while it was being changed.... however this only works when i po it in the terminal..

## UPDATE

now getting these warnings

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSEntityDescription *'
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'Project *' with an expression of type 'NSManagedObject *'
```

using this code.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        Project *currentProj = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:@"Project" insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
```

## UPDATE 2

here is my coredata readFinishing method.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)readFinishing {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (context == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Nil");
    }
    else {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSError *error;
        NSMutableArray *projectDictionaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        for (Project *projects in fetchedObjects) {
            [projectDictionaryArray addObject:projects];
        }
        return projectDictionaryArray;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

hopefully this helps shed some light.. I have been working on this for days.. :( lol

## UPDATE 3

I think I may have found the problem.... in the core data object class I decided to randomly look at I found this..

[image]

updated to dynamic and testing now...

Comment: Remove `currentProject = [[Project alloc] init];` from that code and show the code for the `readFinishing` method.

Comment: I have updated with the code

Comment: Your `Project` class is auto-generated? Any modifications you made? All properties it has are defined in the model? Show the code for the class and maybe a screenshot of the model.

Comment: I'm confused, you've got two updates that appear to have changed the code you're using and what the error is. Please rewrite your question, start over from scratch so there are no updates. Just show the current code you have, and describe what doesn't work/errors you're getting.

Comment: Yep! @synthesize in a core data class will screw you up.

Comment: hey is this your original code or did you get it from somewhere/modifying it.  i one time had a variable that was actually also a method. so when I would nslog out the value of the property the code worked and when i commented that out for delivery it stopped working.  it was because by accessing the property i was actually running a method. just a thought.

Comment: the reason i ask if it's your original code is that you'd know if you wrote it so that a property is actually a method, where otherwise it might be hiding.

Comment: the @dynamic fixed the issue.. obviously i added hasChange after I automatically generated teh coredata objecrt.. then because s is close to d on the keyboard I managed to fluff it up due to code complete AND my incompetience..

Answer (score 3):

CoreData objects must be assigned to a context, and need to be created usually using `NSEntitiyDescription`

```
+ (id)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

like:

```
Product *newProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

More on creating of managed objects in code can be found for example [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-CJBDBHCB)

Comment: am I supposed to put that top line of code somewhere?

Comment: Nope, that is just the definition taken from the documentation on NSEntityDescription for your reference ; i have also added a link to documentation regarding your question

Comment: okay I have tried your code.. this is what I have done **NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        Project *currentProj = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:@"Project" insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
        ** for some reason I am getting these warnings..Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSEntityDescription *'
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'Project *' with an expression of type 'NSManagedObject *'

Comment: Sorry, my fault - copy and paste error - see the corrected lien for generation of the object! The version before would have needed an NSEntityDesc ription object instead of just the entity name.

Comment: okay, no errors on that.. my last question is am I able then to pass an item from the array that contains multiple Product say like this ** newProduct = [tempFinishing objectAtIndex:i];** or do I have to go about it some otherway?

Comment: if you only want to assign you don't need to create a new object first. you can do for example Product *myProduct = [tempFinishing objectAtIndex:i]; but outside the loop newProduct of course doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Yea, that comes back to my original problem that one of the attributes on it comes back as nil untill i go through that stupid output order.

Comment: than maybe Wain is on the right track when he asks for the readFinish method. note hasChange is a dangerous propertyName since hasChanges exists in NSManagedObject

Answer (score 0):

There is a few problems:

```
currentProject = [[Project alloc] init];
currentProject = [tempFinishing objectAtIndex:i];
```

1) you can't create Project as `[[Project alloc] init];` but you have to use

```
Project *newProject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project"
inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

2) Second line `currentProject = [tempFinishing objectAtIndex:i];` rewrites object "created" at line before it.

3) All your code (that was not generated by xCode) have to be in Project subclass. Because once you'll regenerate Projects class by xCode it will rewrite all your custom code. Thus consider to use [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator).

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your code, I have found that "Project" is an entity of Core Data.
So, In this piece of code, You should not create an entity like this, the way you are doing;

```
  for (int i = 0; i < [tempFinishing count]; i++) {
       currentProject = [[Project alloc] init];
       currentProject = [tempFinishing objectAtIndex:i];

       if ([currentProject.hasChange isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
       }
}

//Instead you should use the code like this:-

  for (int i = 0; i < [tempFinishing count]; i++) {

       //currentProject = [[Project alloc] init]; //Delete this line of code...
         currentProject = [tempFinishing objectAtIndex:i]; 

//And, you should read an attribute/property value of an entity like this

        [currentProject valueForKey:@"hasChange"];
//So, 

        if ([[currentProject valueForKey:@"hasChange"] isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
        }
}
```